# How to set a specific package path for CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake

My colleague wrote a `CMakeLists.txt`, which contains things as below:

```
find_package(OpenCV 3 REQUIRED
  COMPONENTS
    opencv_core
    opencv_imgproc
    opencv_imgcodecs
  CONFIG
)
```

As the project needs these components of Opencv3, my colleague downloaded the whole Opencv3, of course, it works.

But the whole Opencv3 is too big, so I get only the necessary lib files: libopencv_core.so, libopencv_imgproc.so and libopencv_imgcodecs.so and try to replace the whole Opencv3. The three so files are put here: `/opt/opencv3/`.

I don't know how to tell the CMakeLists.txt to look for the components of Opencv3 at the specific path instead of the path by default.

I'm totally a newbie on writing CMakeLists.txt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake `find_package()` finds and configure project dependencies in CMake using two modes of operation, Module and Config, as described in its [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html).

In Module mode (not your case), it looks for a `Find<package>.cmake` file inside `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`. This file searches for header files and libraries and set the necessary CMake variables in case of success.

In your case it is using Config, as requested by the `CONFIG` keyword. In Config mode CMake looks for for a `<name>Config.cmake` file or `<lowercase-name>-config.cmake`.
These config files describe the version of the dependency and the location of header files and library modules.

So you should look for `OpenCVConfig.cmake` or `opencv-config.cmake` in `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` or in `OpenCV_DIR`.
Please note that you have to `set(OpenCV_DIR ...)` before calling `find_package()`.

Comment: I've checked the <name>Config.cmake and found the path about OpenCV3. But the `<name>Config.cmake` file or `<lowercase-name>-config.cmake` is generated automatically. So I think I should only modify the `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: My question is how to make the `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: Those files are generated automatically when you install OpenCV I presume. If you want it to install fewer libraries you have to modify its CMakeLists.txt and the config templates <name>Config.cmake.in You can't simply pick a subset of those libraries and copy those in another location (you'll also need the header files and the <name>Config.cmake ...). You could tweak by hand the generated <name>Config.cmake but it doesn't seem very clean to me.